# How to solve this "Jumping numbers" task

Tags: python

Implement the is_jumping function, which accepts the number number and returns the string JUMPING, if each digit in the number differs from the adjacent one by 1. If the condition is not met - the string NOT JUMPING.

```
def is_jumping(number: int) -> str:
    newStr = str(number)
    for i in range(len(newStr)):
        if len(newStr) == 1:
            return "JUMPING"
        elif int(newStr[i + 1]) - int(newStr[i]) == 1:
            return "JUMPING"
        else: return "NOT JUMPING"
```

> AssertionError: assert is_jumping(12543) == "NOT JUMPING", ( "Function 'is_jumping' should return 'NOT JUMPING' " "when number is 12543" )

Where is a problem? why can not pass number 12543? Thank you!

UPD

According to your advice I made some change, but still it doesn't work. Any chance to make my code work?

```
def is_jumping(number: int) -> str:
   newStr = str(number)
   
   for i in range(len(newStr) - 1):
       if int(newStr[i + 1]) - int(newStr[i]) != 1 or int(newStr[i + 1]) - int(newStr[i]) != -1:
           return "NOT JUMPING"
       
   return "JUMPING"
```

@Michael Butscher @bbbbbbbbb @Johnny

Comment: because 2 and 5 are adjacent and are not differing by 1

Comment: It returns "JUMPING" before checking all adjacent numbers. Usual approach is to only return "NOT JUMPING" in the loop and to return "JUMPING" after the loop (which is only reached after all adjacent numbers were checked).

Comment: `elif int(newStr[i + 1]) - int(newStr[i]) == 1:` Will give and `IndexError` on the last digit.

Comment: You are returning too soon. Your code never makes it through more than one iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems in your code already explained in the comment section.

Regardless, no need to convert your input number to a string; try this:

```
def is_jumping(num: int) -> str:
    while num >= 10:
        x = num % 10
        num //= 10
        if num % 10 not in [x - 1, x + 1]:
            return "NOT JUMPING"
    return "JUMPING"
```